# How to avoid doing a query each time loop runs? (optimize code)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * 
                     FROM users 
                     ORDER BY username ASC");
while($user = $query->fetch_object()) {
$if_inside = $db->query("SELECT member_id 
                         FROM project_members 
                         WHERE member_id='$user->id' 
                         UNION 
                         SELECT admin_id 
                         FROM project_admins 
                         WHERE admin_id='$user->id'")->num_rows;
if($if_inside < 1) { // if not already in project 
?> 
<option value="<?php echo $user->username; ?>"> 
               <?php echo $user->username; ?> </option>
 <?php
 } 
 }
 ?>
```

How would I optimize the code above? If I have 100 users in my database then it would query 100 times, and it is already slow (i have 2 users)

Is there a better way to check if an user is already in the project?

Comment: Why don't you fetch all the users from the project then run them against the `id` of said user to see if they are in the project? Or you could do some sort of `JOIN`

Comment: I have to get all users from both `project_members` and `project_admins`, thats why I am using an `UNION`. How would I go about matching two values received from the query TO the user id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$sql = $db->query("Select distinct username from users where username not in (select member_id from project_members union select admin_id from project_admins) order by username ASC");
$queryResult = $sql->fetch_all();

foreach($queryResult as $username) {
    echo "<option value='" . $username . "'>" .  $username . "</option>";
}
```

Do a single hit against the database for all usernames not in either project_members or project_admins and then foreach over the results to display.